# Get SUM of Reference table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

tblOrders

```
OrderId totalamount  OrderStatus
 01        1000           4
 02        2000           4
```

tblCart

```
CartId    OrderId   NetPrice 
  05         01          400
  06         01          650
  07         02          750
  08         02          1350
```

Desired Result:

```
OrderId  totalamount  OrderStatus  NetPrice ItemCount
  01        1000           4         1050      2
  02        2000           4         2100      2
```

I want to achieve the JOIN of two tables with `SUM(Netprice)` based on `OrderId Link`

I tried doing this using SQL Query for a Stored Procedure but its giving ambiguous column error.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query,

```
select t1.OrderId, t1.totalamount, tl1.OrderStatus, sum(t2.NetPrice) as NetPrice , 
count(1) as ItemCount from
tblOrders t1
inner join tblCart  t2
on (t1.OrderId = t2.OrderId)
group by t1.OrderId, t1.totalamount, tl1.OrderStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all columns from the orders table and summarized data from the other, you might find that `apply` is helpful:

```
select o.*, c.*
from tblOrders o outer apply
     (select sum(c.netprice) as netprice, count(*) as itemcount
      from tblCart c
      where c.OrderId = o.OrderId
     ) c;
```